# I am getting an issue while using swift package manager

Tags: ios, swift, swift-package-manager

[image]

I am getting error

> :0: error: no such file or directory: 'package'

why its happening.

Comment: You should check that your Swift install is correct.

Answer (score 0):

It probably means that you did not install Swift Package Manager. Download it from https://swift.org/download/.